# How to build Android platform tool?

Tags: android

I want to build dexdump in android  platform-tools

So I downloaded the android source and modify the dexdump code(dalvik/dexdump/DexDump.cpp).

but I don't know rebuilding my modified DexDump.cpp

Comment: Hey, did you manage to build dexdump successfully in the end? I'm still having problems with this.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer

```
$ cd ~/WORKING_DIRECTORY
$ . build/envsetup.sh
$ mm dexdump
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the GCC or G++ Multilib compiler

Install using

```
sudo apt-get install g++-multilib gcc-multilib
```

Then compile:

```
 gcc -x c++ DexDump.cpp -lstdc++
```